# How can I set a variable In HTML for RGBA?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

In my HTML code, there is a repetition of using the same, RGB values, in testing, I am changing the colors frequently, so I was hoping there is a way to have the RGB value set or defined somewhere.

**I want to stress that, I don't want the ALPHA value set in the RGBA.**

For example:

```
var COLOR = 189,28,50 <br>
...<br>
fill="rgba(COLOR,0.7
```

[image: This is my Code]

Comment: HTML doesn't have variables. You could use JavaScript variables to acheive this. I don't think that [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) woud work here since `fill` isn't the same as `style`

Comment: @Samathingamajig how would I do this with JS?

Comment: Stressing what you dont want but `var COLOR = 189,28,50` is not even valid javascript.

Comment: @mardubbles I didn't know that, sorry

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer would be using CSS Custom Properties (Variables) which is very easy and straightforward technique.
Declaring a custom property is done using a (custom property name) begins with a double hyphen (--), and then a property value which is any valid CSS value like black, yellow, . Like any other property, this is written inside a ruleset, so it is a set of rules that needs to be written in the style.css file.
then step 2 would be defining these custom property inside your :root pseudo-class, so that it can be applied for global usage across your entire html doc.
Hope you got the answer.
[HTML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF4eJ.png)
[CSS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7i7E.png)

Mozilla Documentation Link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties